# .when issue in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to run below code but its throwing error. it seems like in handlebar.compile i am passing null(a[j]), which i think is occurring because control is not entering into .when's function as i dont see any log in console. i may be wrong. but please healp me in correcting it.

code:

```
 if (pageName.page === "dashboard") {
      $.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/dashboard',function (data){
           var a = new Array(data.length);
           console.log(data);

           $.when(function(){
                console.log("inside function 1");
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length;) {
                     console.log("inside funct 1 for loop");
                     $.get('commonCore/templates/' + data[i].templateHtml , function(html) {
                          a[i]=html;
                          i++;
                          console.log("inside funct 2" + i +"  " + html);
                     });
                }
           }).then(function(d) {
                for (var j = 0;j < data.length; j++) {
                     filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(a[j]);
                     replaceFilterTemplate(data[i].classids);
                }
           });
      });
 }
```

JSON :

```
[
    {
        "templateHtml": "dashBoardLeftInsight.html",
        "classSelect": "leftpanel"
    },
    {
        "templateHtml": "dcdcsFilterOptions.html",
        "classSelect": "dcdcsOptions"
    },
    {
        "templateHtml": "advanceFilterOptions.html",
        "classSelect": "advancedOptions"
    },
    {
        "templateHtml": "reportFilterOptions.html",
        "classSelect": "reportdashboard"
    }
]
```

Comment: what are you trying to do

Comment: Thats weird use of `$.when`. It takes `One or more Deferred objects, or plain JavaScript objects` and you are passing it a function

Comment: Uncaught Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined... this is error its show in console

Answer (score 0):

`$.when` expects a promise object as its argument, if a non promise is passed then it will assume it as a resolved object and will call the success callbacks.

In your case you are passing a function as the argument which will trigger the success callbacks before the actual ajax requests are completed.

Try

```
if (pageName.page === "dashboard") {
    $.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/dashboard', function (data) {

        var requests = $.map(data, function (rec, i) {
            return $.get('commonCore/templates/' + rec.templateHtml, function (html) {
                console.log("inside funct 2" + i + "  " + html);
            });
        });

        $.when.apply($, requests).then(function () {
            return $.map(arguments, function (args) {
                return args[0]
            });
        }).done(function (responses) {
            $.each(responses, function (i, response) {
                filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(response);

                replaceFilterTemplate(data[i].classids);
            })
        })
    });
}
```

PoC: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HLEv8/)

Answer (score 0):

I believe your sub requests are not synchronized with your handler function that makes use of them. I would try something like this:

```
if (pageName.page === "dashboard") {
  $.getJSON('api/filterTemplate/dashboard',function (data){
       var a = new Array(data.length);
       console.log(data);
       var allRequests = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length;) {
                 console.log("inside funct 1 for loop");
                var request =  $.get('commonCore/templates/' + data[i].templateHtml , function(html) {
                      a[i]=html;
                      i++;
                      console.log("inside funct 2" + i +"  " + html);
                 });
             allrequests.push(request);
            }



       $.when.apply($, allRequests).then(function(d) {
            for (var j = 0;j < data.length; j++) {
                 filterTemplate = Handlebars.compile(a[j]);
                 replaceFilterTemplate(data[i].classids);
            }
       });
  });
```

}